# Is it fine to use the same mkcert certificate for both your frontend and backend?

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, vite

I'm developing a webapp that uses vite on the frontend for my local testing environment and also a separate API backend.

I used `mkcert` to generate a local dev certificate and am using that one for the backend.

My question is, for my frontend dev environment I *also* can use a certificate, as shown here in the vite config:

```
server: {
  https: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
  },
  proxy: {
    '/v1': {
      target: 'https://127.0.0.1:8080'
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: can I use this same generated certificate (`key.pem` and `cert.pem`) for my backend *and* frontend servers? It *seems* to work okay, but I'm not sure of the implications for this.

I generated my `mkcert` certificate using the following command:

```
mkcert localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1 192.168.1.96
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes you can**

---

##### Explanation:

The certificate doesn't make difference of "frontend" or "backend" things.

It "take" only the FQDN given on creation and generally a certificate is valid for use on a single fully qualified domain name (FQDN), but it's out of scope of this question.

What I mean is, if you create a certificate for only `127.0.0.1` and you try to load it from `192.168.1.96`, you will see the certificate as invalid.

In your case, as you created the certificate for both local network IP and the public IP, then whatever you load the cert from localhost or 192.168.1.96, the certificate is valid.